# Time series imputation via dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, grouping

Given dataset:

```
Category         Date    a    b  
      aa   2017-01-01    5    1
      aa   2017-01-03    1    3
      bb   2017-01-01    2    4
      bb   2017-01-02    3    5
      bb   2017-01-03    2    3
      cc   2017-01-03    3    3
     ...
```

I need to impute observations for each category in given dataset. For column `a` I need to impute `0` and for b - last observed value. For this example I have to obtain this:

```
 Category         Date    a    b  
       aa   2017-01-01    5    1
       aa   2017-01-02    0    1
       aa   2017-01-03    1    3
       bb   2017-01-01    2    4
       bb   2017-01-02    3    5
       bb   2017-01-03    2    3
       cc   2017-01-01    0    0   # start date for cc category, so '0'        
       cc   2017-01-02    0    0
       cc   2017-01-03    3    3
     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Category = sort(rep(paste0(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )], letters[seq( from = 1, to = 3 )]),3)),
  Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-03"), by = "day"),3)
  )

df2 <- data.frame(Category = c("aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "cc"),
           Date = c("2017-01-01","2017-01-03","2017-01-01","2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-03"),
           a = c(5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3),
           b = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3)
           )
df2$Date = as.Date(df2$Date)

left_join(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(a = ifelse(is.na(a), 0, a),
         b = ifelse(is.na(b), dplyr::lag(b,n=1,default=0),b),
         b = ifelse(is.na(b), dplyr::lag(b,n=1,default=0),b))
```

In no way is this an elegant solution but you could create a separate data frame with all the rows you want to end up with (just use rep and seq).

Then left join your old dataframe onto this and use lag windows function (needs to be done twice).

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Just remembered coalesce is dplyr.


`left(join(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(a = coalesce(a,0),
         b = coalesce(b,lag(b,n=1,default=0), lag(b,n=2,default=0)))`